# How to exclude element from parent CSS

Tags: html, css, padding, divider

I have a question to let an HR element ignore the padding from the div it is placed in.
It has a padding of: `padding:0 20px 0 20px;`, but that effects my header and text, which i like.
But I want to use the HR tag as a 100% divider.

It looks like this:

```
*------------*
| Header tag |
| ---------- |
| some text  |
| some text  |
*------------*
```

But how can I make it so that it works like this:

```
*------------*
| Header tag |
+------------+
| some text  |
| some text  |
*------------*
```

So that the HR element is on actual 100% width, so excluding the padding.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a border instead?

Comment: Show your HTML and CSS and tell exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @chris try to use my answer below for simplest usage.

Answer (score 2):

By using a negative margin, which is as much as the padding.

In this HTML code:

```
<div>
    Text
    <hr />
    Text
</div>
```

Use this CSS:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
hr {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Also see this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1t2fLsmm/).